# Z-index конфликтует с js

Tags: html, css, javascript

Всем привет! Есть код:

HTML:

```
div id="cate"
```

CSS:

```
#cate {
position: absolute;
left: 205px;
top: 63.7px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: url('images/cate2.png') no-repeat;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div#cate").click(function() {
   $(this).animate({ top: '150px' });
 });
});
```

Все хорошо, но как прописываешь в `css 'z-index: -999'` функции `js` пропадают. Как же быть? Help!

Comment: Не может быть такого, чтобы из-за css не работал JS.
И кстати, зачем кавычки 'z-index: -999'?

Comment: Во-первых, у вас есть специальная кнопочка, чтобы сделать текст кодом.

Comment: '' - Это как цитата.
Элемент виден, но анимация пропадает.

Comment: {} — а это как код.

Comment: А картинкой как? И еще надо вниз.. И что бы он под другой блок смог зайти..

Comment: Если надо картинкой, то вставляете картинку. Если нада не влево, а вниз, то делаете вниз, элементарно же. Чтобы под другой блок смог зайти, нужно одному блоку сделать z-index: 1, а другому — 2.

Comment: Мдя, судя по вопросам — очередной новичек, который вообще не рубит в ЦСС и ХТМЛ, но хочет сделать какой-то сайт. Учите матчасть и самые основы ЦСС, ХТМЛ и Яваскрипта, а не задавайте кучу элементарнейших вопросов — ну нельзя же по каждой мелочи генерировать простыни вопросов, нужно выучить чуть-чуть.

Comment: @bifot, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отрицательный индекс прячет элемент и вы его просто не видите, соответственно, не видите, как он анимируется.

Вот [песочница](http://jsfiddle.net/fhXXr/1/), всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Первый `top: 63.7px;` значение должно быть больше наследующих т.е больше

```
$(this).animate({ top: '150px' });
```

Значение родителя должно быть больше наследников.